# Excel (MAC) to SQL Server connection using macro

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, macos, odbc

I have a macro enabled Excel sheet in MAC where I have some data and want to export it to SQL Server. I am trying to truncate the target table first and then insert but my code is not working. The code needs to be working across both MAC and Windows. Please help.

```
    Sub Export_Click()
    Dim sqlstring As String
    Dim connstring As String
    Dim sLogin As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim defaultDate As String
    Dim sql As String, bulkSql As String
    Dim intImportRow As Integer
    Dim Product, Resource As String
    Dim name, address as String

    'sLogin = "Uid=$;Pwd=$;"
    'sqlstringfirma = "SELECT * from tableA"
    connstring = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=ServerIP;DATABASE=databse;UID=uid;PWD=pwd"
    sql_trunc = "truncate table tableA"
    sql_commit = "commit"
    sql_query = "select * from table tableA"

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("A1"), sql:=sql_trunc)
        .BackgroundQuery = False
        '.Refresh
    End With

    intImportRow = 10
    
Do Until .Cells(intImportRow, 1) = ""
    Product = .Cells(intImportRow, 1)
    Resource = .Cells(intImportRow, 2)
    sql_insert = "insert into tableA (name, address) values ('" & name & "', '" & address & "')"
    
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("A1"), 
    sql:=sql_insert)
       .BackgroundQuery = False
       .Refr
    
    intImportRow = intImportRow + 1
            Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: How is the code not working? Are you getting a specific error message? If so edit your question to include the error message - as text.

Comment: There is no response when I click the button. @AlwaysLearning